# error with ownership

Tags: users

"The specified file temporary://filelo2Fkx could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log."

ANYWAY what I am getting is everything minus theme and all images but strangely my multi site folders in root drupal sites folder are all working fine.

In the end I solved it by putting the root subfolder in sites along with other multi-sites. No amount of changing permissions or ownership or clean install or dropping and recreating database worked until then...which is very odd because it used to before I took the site down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and change the permission of the folder 'sites/all/files' to give it 777 permission in your drupal installation and see if this works.

Comment: Thanks I have already done that but still get same error because now I have no clue what ownership should be on all the folders.

Comment: I think giving the owner 777 permission and others only read permissions should work. Did you already try this?

Comment: I have tried 777 root:apache and tried apache:apache and root:root on files folder but still get the error.

Comment: weirdly my multi-sites listed in sites folder are all fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with temporary directory (/tmp is the default).

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040718/file-system-permission-error-while-installing-drupal-modules

M.

Comment: Nothing is working

Comment: Ok. Have you opened an assistance/help ticket with your ISP ? M.

Comment: it is an unmanaged VPS

Comment: I think what I will try doing is do vanilla install and then just bring sql for those one's not working.